# A concrete example of fuzzy logic

Tags: java, language-agnostic, logic, fuzzy-logic

I remember reading a book about fuzzy logic and how it was being used in devices like washing machines. I haven't yet encountered a concrete example of this in code though. Do you know of any?

Comment: Do you mean [fuzzy logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_logic)?

Comment: What is "grey logic"? Can you post a link?

Comment: You're right MikeJ-UK, I mean fuzzy logic.

Comment: @Oded: Here's a wikipedia link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_logic

Comment: @James - I am familiar with "fuzzy logic". It's "grey logic" that I was wondering about...

Comment: @Oded: No idea where I picked up that expression but it have come from an article like this one: http://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2009/03/090317095030.htm

Comment: I've got a couple of examples on my blog: http://fuzzyfsharp.wordpress.com/

Comment: Please post excerpts here if you can as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend "The Fuzzy Systems Handbook", by Earl Cox.  Though I have not used the included source code, the book explains both the application of fuzzy logic and the programming mechanics behind it.  Several examples are presented which are from real world solutions.